# About Junit test with database

Tags: mysql, oracle, junit, mocking

I am trying to do junit on a qa machine where no database installed and we cannot connect to databases on other machine.
May I ask is there any way we can mock a database in junit? Like we test with hadoop.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try a local database like Hypersonic or Derby.

Answer (score 1):

Actually using hsql could be very helpful in test:)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  You could use a really simple database like H2 instead of Oracle or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your one option is to use h2database. Just add following dependency to your *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.194</version>
</dependency>
```

Add *application.properties* file under test folder in your spring boot project.
(Spring will look for properties file under test folder first while executing Junit tests)

Just replace all the db params to following values:

```
spring.az.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

spring.az.datasource.drive-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

In your test files using @BeforeClass (Junit 5) or @BeforeAll (Junit 4) annotations, create a database identical to your production database.

```
@Autowired
AzDataConfiguration azData;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    jt = new JdbcTemplate(azData.azdataSource());
    jt.execute(Constant.creatAzureTable);
}
```

Please refer this for details: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/jdbc.html